# When dropping a partition on InnoDB table does mysql flush pages in the whole table or only in a partition to be dropped?

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning, mysql-5.7

When issuing `ALTER TABLE .. DROP PARTITION p1` mysql have to flush pages to disk. My question is: does mysql flush pages in the whole table (in each partition) or only in a partition to be dropped? MySQL server 5.7

table partition exp. is: `PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt))`

Comment: Are you asking about flushing from the buffer_pool?  Or about disk activity after the `DROP`, which may be noticeable.  And you say "flush to disk" -- what if it chooses to remove them from the buffer_pool without writing to disk.

Comment: "what if it chooses to remove them from the buffer_pool without writing to disk.". Hmm, I always thougt that mysql flushes dirty pages to disk before deleting a partition (not allowing tham to stay in buffer pool).
Docs say that clean pages stay in bp (and will be evicted eventually, asyncroniosly), but I have no idea what about dirty pages, should they stay in bp or should they be flushed to disk (to .ibd file) before dropping a partition (and if this the case, what pages are to be flushed - the ones that belong to the partition to be dropped or pages in the whole table).

Comment: In general, I have heavy loaded system (lots rps, 40k+) and when I drop a partition, server experiencing a performance drop. And I try to figure out what couses it: locks on the partitioned table (hard to acquire a metadata-lock coz table very popular) or internal activities while dropping a partition (like flushing dirty pages).
Server is on linux, ext4, good ssd. Dropping a partition file (every day one file) (50G each) should be fast from disk perspective (I dont see the disk to suffer when partition is being dropped and I dont see, that acquiring a metadata-lock on table takes much time).

Comment: It's hard to distinguish whether the buffer_pool is the issue or the OS freeing up the blocks of the partition is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MySQL 5.7 Documentation under the subheading `Affected DDL statements`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-partitioning-excerpt/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-locking.html), here is what says about Locking for DDL on Partitioned Tables:

> CREATE VIEW does not cause any locks.
>
> ALTER TABLE ... EXCHANGE PARTITION prunes locks; only the exchanged
> table and the exchanged partition are locked.
>
> ALTER TABLE ... TRUNCATE PARTITION prunes locks; only the partitions
> to be emptied are locked.
>
> In addition, ALTER TABLE statements take metadata locks on the table
> level.

As far as I can see in that page, it locks the table's metadata. There is nothing here suggesting that all the `.ibd` files of the other partitions need to be flushed. It would affect only those files involved.

In your case, it would involve the following steps:

- Acquire metadata lock on the `.par` file of the partitioned table
- Update list of partitions in the `.par` file
- Remove locks of `.ibd` you are going to drop
- Unlock the `.par` file

NOTE : Dropping a partition is DDL not DML.

### DIRECT ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION

Only partition to be dropped